# Internal Server Error with Routing and Geoencoding

Tags: here-api

I signed up for an account to try out the REST geoencoding and the routing APIs. In both scenarios, I am getting a 500 internal server error with no details. Both example codes I have taken straight from the documentation and replaced my API key.

`https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=V6...oI&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled`

`https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/search/6.2/geocode.json?languages=en-US&maxresults=4&searchtext=Sunnyvale&apiKey=V6...oI`

In both instances I get a generic 500 Internal Server error

```
{
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "error_description": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

I have tried signing up for two accounts just in case there was an issue with the first, but get the same response.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with my API key and it worked fine. It could have been a momentary issue, although I don't see any incidents in our status page (https://status.here.com/status). Can you try again please?